# Is there any difference between DHCP helper & DHCP relay agent

Tags: dhcp

The DHCP helper is the device that knows where the DHCP server is
The DHCP agent knows where the helper is on the network and points a device to the router or switch ..

Answer (score 4):

A DHCP relay agent receives DHCP requests and forwards them to configured IP addresses on another subnet.  It may modify the DHCP request packet.  This behaviour is outlined in
[RFC 1542](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3046)
[RFC 2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3046)
[RFC 3046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3046)

IP helper / UDP helper provides facilities for forwarding or re-broadcasting UDP packets (not just DHCP requests) across a router.